# Eclipse plugin development: Get list of all possible quick fixes for an error

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to develop an Eclipse plugin that uses the inbuilt "Quick fix" feature.

I need the `list` of all possible `Quick fixes` for a particular error. 
I am trying to do so by implementing the `QuickFixProcessor` interface to use the method:

```
public IJavaCompletionProposal[] getCorrections(IInvocationContext context, 
                                       IProblemLocation[] locations)`
```

I am struggling to find how can I get instances of `IInvocationContext` and `IProblemLocation[]` in order to call the above method.

Let me know if I am in the wrong direction to get all the possible `Quickfix` solutions for an error.

I am novice to Eclipse plugin development and would appreciate any help. Apologies if I missed any conventions.

Comment: Are you saying you are going to try and call all the quick fix processors declared in the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.quickFixProcessors` extension point to get there proposals?

Comment: Do I need to do that if I want the list of all possible quick-fix solutions to a particular error?

Comment: `IQuickFixProcessor` is an interface you implement to provide additional quick fixes to the Java editor - it isn't for getting the existing proposals.